# Can't create proper spring data custom query using reference field as parameter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, spring-data

I'm trying to make custom spring Data query using field from reference as query 
parameter. When i performed this query via REST i had no results at all:[image: screen1]
I enabled hibernate logs and copy it to H2 console and I got many results:
[image: screen2]

My Flight and Airport entities are very simple[image: screen2]

So what am I doing wrong? I have other simpler methods and they work fine using browser. I tried the same using Query annotation(second method on second screen), but I got same results. (Copied generated sql query to H2 console and received many results but it didn't work via REST).

**EDIT**
I found the solution. I just removed quotation marks from URL and 
it works well :D [image]

Sorry for my inattention.
Regards,

Michal

Comment: please, replace your images with code snippets

Comment: please, post the solution you found as the answer and accept it, so this question is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was very simple. Basically I just removed quotation marks from URL and it works well :D
[image]
Actual method in Repository looks like:

`List findFlightsByFromCityAndToCity(@Param("from") String from, @Param("to") String to);`

Regards,
Michal